# How can I make my search bar filter dates correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The search bar works perfectly, but when searching like this: 2022-08-13 does not appear, I guess because of the format in which ReportDate is...

Now when you search according to the format it delivers [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHkZE.png):

The search bar function is made from the React-Table library, and it looks like this:

```
import { Input, InputGroup, InputRightElement } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { CloseIcon, SearchIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';

export const GlobalFilter = ({ filter, setFilter }) => {
  const [t] = useTranslation('global');
  return (
    <InputGroup borderColor="#6E6B7B" color="#6E6B73">
      <Input
        placeholder={t('tableActions.search')}
        type="text"
        size="md"
        value={filter || ''}
        onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value.toString())}
      />
      <InputRightElement
        children={
          !filter ? (
            <SearchIcon color="#6E6B7B" />
          ) : (
            <CloseIcon
              color="#6E6B7B"
              onClick={() => setFilter('')}
              cursor="pointer"
            />
          )
        }
      />
    </InputGroup>
  );
};
```

My question is, is there a way to search for the simplest date, for example 2022-07-12?

Comment: What does not appear? The value in the search bar or the search results?

Comment: When you search in a similar way to this 2022-07-12 nothing appears in the search results.

Comment: FYI, `e.target.value` is always a string, so there's no reason to call `.toString()` on it.

Comment: If nothing in the results shows up, but the UI is working fine, my best guess is, that the problem is not orginating in your frontend code, but whatever is handling your data and you should start debugging there.